# How to reliably return results from Oracle SQL*Plus to a variable in Korn shell?

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, sqlplus, ksh

Hello Unix/Linux geniae,

When an error occurs in the query, why does the shell variable (OPEN_MODE in this case) contain not only the expected SQL error message but also a listing of all the files in the directory?
I realise it has to do with the backticks and the fact that there is an asterisk in the error message but how can I get the error message back without the directory listing?
Run from command line:

```
$ OPEN_MODE=`sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' <<'EOSQL' 2>/tmp/results.synchro.$$
> set headi off newpa none feedb off
> whenever sqlerror exit failure
> select open_mode from v$database;
> EOSQL
> `
$ echo $OPEN_MODE
select open_mode from v$database   db_space_calculation.ksh     get_emc_schedule_status.ksh set_emc_schedule_status.ksh synchro.ksh  synchro_adsp_adso.cfg synchro_arp_arpt.cfg synchro_xbrl_xbrla.cfg synchro_xbrl_xbrlt.cfg test.sh ERROR at line 1: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available Process ID: 0 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

And run interactively from SQL*Plus to show how the error is normally presented...

```
$ sqlplus '/ as sysdba'

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Jan 15 20:31:04 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> set headi off newpa none feedb off
SQL> whenever sqlerror exit failure
SQL> select open_mode from v$database;
select open_mode from v$database
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Disconnected
```

I have also tried the "piping into read" method but doesn't work either.

```
sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba' <<'EOSQL' 2>/tmp/results.synchro.$$ | read OPEN_MODE
set headi off newpa none feedb off
whenever sqlerror exit failure
select open_mode from v$database;
EOSQL
```

- Has to work in ksh. No bash please.
- $() produces the same results as backticks. The only time I use  backticks in ksh is when calling sqlplus! There are times when $() simply does not work. But that's for another day :-)

Comment: Read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo -- although this is "bash" pitfalls, ksh has the same issue with unquoted variables.

Comment: Glenn,Thank you. It is as simple as quoting the
$ echo $OPEN_MODE as $ echo "$OPEN_MODE" then I get just the message.